# CSS calc() inside flexbox unexpected behaviour

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple buttons inside a flex container (`<div class="itemlist">`) and want the last button to have its own row. This flex container itself is inside another flex container (`<div class="container">`).

To give the last button its own row, I set `flex-basis: 100%;`. Because I don't want the actual button to be that wide, i give it a margin. (I know I could also use a wrapper, but I want to do it without).

A margin of `0 40%` gives the button a width `20%` (= 100% - 2*40%) of the parent container. So far it works as expected. But now I want to give the button a fixed width. Therefore I would logically need to set the margin to `0 calc(50% - wantedWidth/2)`.

When I set the margin of `<button class="ownRow">Special Item</button>` using a simple percent or pixel value, it works just fine, but as soon as i use calc to get the value, the parent flex element changes its width to that of my button, which messes things up.

Why is that the  case?

Fixed value of `margin: 0px 42.3px;` works just fine:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.itemlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ownRow {
  /*margin: 0px calc(50% - 50px);*/
  margin: 0px 42.3px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="itemlist">
    <button>Item 1</button>
    <button>Item 2</button>
    <button>Item 3</button>
    <button>Item 4</button>
    <button class="ownRow">Special Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `margin: 0px calc(50% - 50px);` it doesn't work:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.itemlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ownRow {
  margin: 0px calc(50% - 50px);
  /* margin: 0px 42.3px; */
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="itemlist">
    <button>Item 1</button>
    <button>Item 2</button>
    <button>Item 3</button>
    <button>Item 4</button>
    <button class="ownRow">Special Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This makes no sense for me, because the margin calculated by the browser is the same:

[image]

**Why is there a different behaviour when using calc() for the margin?**

Comment: it's not related to calc() but the use of percentage

Comment: the duplicate is about padding but the same logic happen with margin

Comment: @TemaniAfif But with percentage only it works just fine. Try ´margin: 0px 30%;´, works perfectly.
https://jsfiddle.net/v0dazpfs/
It only starts to break when you add calc() into the mix. So it IS related to calc().

Comment: no, it doesn't work like you are expecting. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/97n814u2/ percentage and pixel doesn't produce the same output. the result get worse if you increase the percentage.